# Integration of a shifted Gaussian multiplied by a Bessel function

Tags: calculus, integration, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I am trying to solve an integral like

$$
F(q, a, b) = \int_0^{+\infty}dx e^{-(x-a)^2/b^2}J_0(qx)x \quad where\quad a, b > 0; q > 0
$$

For a similar result, it is well known that $\int_0^{+\infty}dx e^{-x^2/b^2}J_0(qx)x = \frac{b^2}{2}e^{-q^2 b^2 / 4}$. Is there a simple formula for this integral?

I search and find the same question in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187350/integral-of-bessel-function-with-general-gaussian), but no answer is available.

Comment: This looks equivalent to integral 6.616.1 in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik at a quick glance to me. Is that right?

Comment: It is $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x}J_0(\beta\sqrt{x^2 + 2\gamma x})dx$. How to convert from $\int_0^{+\infty}dx e^{-(x-a)^2/b^2}J_0(qx)x$ to it? Could you please provide a further hints about it? Thanks. @davidlowryduda